# spotlight crashes in High Sierra

Tags: spotlight, macos-high-sierra

Spotlight crashes every time when I search anything starting with certain letters like "a", "c" or "e", while works fine for other letters like "b" or "d". I'm using a MacBook Air, this started to happen after I upgrade to High Sierra, but didn't happen when in Sierra.

When I look at logs in console, it says

```
Oct 16 19:01:58 Jackys-MacBook-Air Spotlight[1131]: objc[1131]: Class SPWebHistoryResult is implemented in both 

/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Spotlight.framework/Versions/A/Spotlight (0x7fff9388aeb0) 

and 

/System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight (0x1080c0a68).

One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Tried reindexing, reinstall OS X 10.13, nothing helped. It also happens in safe mode too. I'm thinking it might be something wrong with Xcode, but not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the Chinese dictionary (CC-CEDICT) I installed in Dictionary app caused the issue. I removed the dictionary and it works fine for me.

This is how I found the cause.
I tried turning off spotlight search target one by one (System Preference > Spotlight > Search Results tab)
When I turn off the *Definition*, Spotlight worked fine for me, and I knew *Definition* uses dictionary app for its source, so I turn off target dictionaries one by one in dictionary preference.
In this way, you should be able to find actual cause of the spotlight problem.

Comment: For me, it is "美林韦氏大学词典.dictionary" that stuck.